# How to create a Jmeter test of jdbc request in Java code

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter

I want to build a new jdbc test in Java program, this is my code:

```
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterPropertiesFile.getPath());

StandardJMeterEngine standardJMeterEngine = new StandardJMeterEngine();
HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
testPlan.setTestPlanClasspath("C:\\Users\\jinzha\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\mysql\\mysql-connector-java\\5.1.20\\66a2a9c6561dc2c3c6f0b924681c305be78f3377\\mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar");

//jdbc configuration sample
DataSourceElement dataSourceElement = createDatasource();
//jdbc sample
JDBCSampler sampler = createJdbcSampler();

LoopController loopController = createLoopController();
loopController.addTestElement(sampler);

ThreadGroup threadGroup = createThreadGroup();
threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);

testPlanTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
testPlanTree.add("loopController", loopController);
testPlanTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
testPlanTree.add("JDBCDataSource", dataSourceElement);
testPlanTree.add("JDBCSampler",sampler);
```

Could anyone show me the correct way?

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal working configuration would be something like:

1. [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration):

   ```
   DataSourceElement jdbcDataSource = new DataSourceElement();
   jdbcDataSource.setName("JDBC Connection Configuration");
   jdbcDataSource.setProperty("dataSource", "foo");
   jdbcDataSource.setProperty("dbUrl", "jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306/mysql");
   jdbcDataSource.setProperty("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   jdbcDataSource.setProperty("username", "root");
   jdbcDataSource.setProperty("password", "secret");
   jdbcDataSource.setProperty("poolMax", "0");
   jdbcDataSource.setProperty("connectionAge", "5000");
   jdbcDataSource.setProperty("timeout", "10000");
   jdbcDataSource.setProperty("trimInterval", "60000");
   jdbcDataSource.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, DataSourceElement.class.getName());
   jdbcDataSource.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestBeanGUI.class.getName());
   ```
2. [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) Sampler:

   ```
   JDBCSampler jdbcSampler = new JDBCSampler();
   jdbcSampler.setName("JDBC Request");
   jdbcSampler.setProperty("dataSource", "foo");
   jdbcSampler.setProperty("queryType", "Select Statement");
   jdbcSampler.setProperty("query", "select * from help_topic limit 5;");
   jdbcSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, JDBCSampler.class.getName());
   jdbcSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestBeanGUI.class.getName());
   ```

Putting everything together:

```
package com.blazemeter;

import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.gui.TestBeanGUI;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final String jmeterHome = "c:/apps/jmeter";

        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterHome + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "bin"
                + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "jmeter.properties");

        HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

        DataSourceElement jdbcDataSource = new DataSourceElement();
        jdbcDataSource.setName("JDBC Connection Configuration");
        jdbcDataSource.setProperty("dataSource", "foo");
        jdbcDataSource.setProperty("dbUrl", "jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.100:3306/mysql");
        jdbcDataSource.setProperty("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        jdbcDataSource.setProperty("username", "root");
        jdbcDataSource.setProperty("password", "secret");
        jdbcDataSource.setProperty("poolMax", "0");
        jdbcDataSource.setProperty("connectionAge", "5000");
        jdbcDataSource.setProperty("timeout", "10000");
        jdbcDataSource.setProperty("trimInterval", "60000");
        jdbcDataSource.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, DataSourceElement.class.getName());
        jdbcDataSource.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestBeanGUI.class.getName());

        JDBCSampler jdbcSampler = new JDBCSampler();
        jdbcSampler.setName("JDBC Request");
        jdbcSampler.setProperty("dataSource", "foo");
        jdbcSampler.setProperty("queryType", "Select Statement");
        jdbcSampler.setProperty("query", "select * from help_topic limit 5;");
        jdbcSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, JDBCSampler.class.getName());
        jdbcSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestBeanGUI.class.getName());

        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(1);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
        loopController.initialize();

        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("JMeter JDBC Test Plan");
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
        testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

        testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
        HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
        threadGroupHashTree.add(jdbcDataSource);
        threadGroupHashTree.add(jdbcSampler);

        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + System.getProperty("file.separator")
                + "bin" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "jdbc.jmx"));


        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }

        String logFile = jmeterHome + System.getProperty("file.separator") +
                "bin" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "jdbc.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();

        System.exit(0);


    }
}
```

Upon execution the above test plan will generate `jdbc.jmx` test plan in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and `jdbc.jtl` result file at the same location if everything goes well.

References:

- [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui/)
- [JMeter From Code Example Project](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/)

Comment: thank you so much, it works and generate correct reports, while there are some exception happends as follow:  ------------Something bad happened when loading bean info for bean class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler
java.lang.NullPointerException: null--------------------------- Thanks a lot for the upon answer

Answer (score 1):

I use this example, it also happened `Something bad happened when loading bean info for bean class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler java.lang.NullPointerException`, and I find the problem by debugging the source code.

at the beginning of this function, we need to add a `java.util.Locale instance`:
`JMeterUtils.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());`